# SUMIFS and EOMONTH formula to calculate monthly spending

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I’d love some advice on combining two formulas in Google Sheets.

Goal: I want to calculate my monthly spending based on a dropdown list of categories I've set up (e.g. Food/Groceries, Shopping, Vehicle...etc).

Formula 1:

This formula calculates the total cost (E) for a specific dropdown list of categories(C) (e.g. J111 relates to the ‘Food/Groceries’ category)

```
=if(isblank($J111), "", sumif($C:$C,$J111,$E:$E))
```

Formula 2:

This formula calculates total cost(E) over a certain date(A) range (J115 = 01/01/2019 = January)

```
=SUMIFS($E:$E, $A:$A,">="&$J115,$E:$E,"<="&EOMONTH($J115,0))
```

I would love to combine these formulas to calculate the total cost(E) over a certain date(A) range (J115 = January) for a specific category(C) (e.g. J111 = ‘Food/Groceries’).

That way I can calculate my Food/Groceries spending for each month of the year etc.

I'm not that good with formulas and can't seem to combine them without getting errors.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Can you add the formulas you tried that didn't work?  That will help people identify exactly what you're having problems with so they can explain the solution better.

Answer (score 0):

ACTUALLY, I think I've figured it out. Originally I was trying:

If the Category (C) matches J111 (Food/Groceries) calculate cost (E), but only if the date (A) of the cost is >/= J115 (1-January-2019) or

=SUMIFS($C:$C,$J111,$E:$E, $A:$A,">="&$J115,$E:$E,"<="&EOMONTH($J115,0))

The error I get is: 'Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size.'

But I made some changes and I'm having success with this variation:

=SUMIFS($E:$E,$C:$C,$J111, $A:$A,">="&$J115,$E:$E,"<="&EOMONTH($J115,0))

Thanks anyway! :)